# pyQt and threading application crash

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, pyqt

I wrote simple program which has pyQt interface with 2 buttons (start and cancel). Start button runs some calculations in the background (by starting update function) and thanks to threading I can still use UI.
But the application crashes after 10sec - 2 minutes. UI just dissapears, program shutdown.

when I use pythonw to run app without console thread crashes after ~25 sec but gui still works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import time
import os


class Class(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        #Some init variables
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #some UI
        self.show()

    def update(self,stop_event):
            while True and not stop_event.isSet():
                self.updateSpeed()
                self.updateDistance()
                self.printLogs()
                self.saveCSV()
                self.guiUpdate()
                time.sleep(1)

    #gui button function
    def initiate(self):
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.c_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.update, args=(self.stop_event,))
        self.c_thread.start()

    #Also gui button function
    def cancelTracking(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.close()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Class()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    ex.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I dont know if I'm doing threading right. I found example like this on stack. I'm quite new to python and I'm using threading for the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is most likely due to calling a GUI function in your separate thread. PyQt GUI calls like `setText()` on a `QLineEdit` are not allowed from a thread. Anything that has PyQt painting outside of the main thread will not work. One way to get around this is to have your thread emit a signal to update the GUI when data is ready. The other way is to have a timer periodically checking for new data and updating the `paintEvent` after a certain time.

**========== EDIT ==========**

To Fix this issue I created a library named `qt_thread_updater`. https://github.com/justengel/qt_thread_updater This works by continuously running a QTimer. When you call `call_latest` the QTimer will run the function in the main thread.

```
from qt_thread_updater import get_updater

lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel('Value: 1')

counter = {'a': 1}

def run_thread():
    while True:
        text = 'Value: {}'.format(counter['a'])
        get_updater().call_latest(lbl.setText, text)
        counter['a'] += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)

th = threading.Thread(target=run_thread)
th.start()
```

**========== END EDIT ==========**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import time
import os


class Class(QtGui.QWidget):

    display_update = QtCore.pyqtSignal() # ADDED

    def __init__(self):
        #Some init variables
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #some UI
        self.display_update.connect(self.guiUpdate) # ADDED
        self.show()

    def update(self):
        while True and not self.stop_event.isSet():
            self.updateSpeed()
            self.updateDistance()
            self.printLogs()
            self.saveCSV()

            # self.guiUpdate()
            self.display_update.emit() # ADDED

            time.sleep(1)

    #gui button function
    def initiate(self):
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.c_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.update)
        self.c_thread.start()

    #Also gui button function
    def cancelTracking(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.close()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Class()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    # ex.update() # - this does nothing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The other thing that could be happening is deadlock from two threads trying to access the same variable. I've read that this shouldn't be possible in python, but I have experienced it from the combination of PySide and other Python C extension libraries.

May also want to join the thread on close or use the `QtGui.QApplication.aboutToQuit` signal to join the thread before the program closes.

Comment: Thanks! It works now like it should ;) no more crashes

Comment: Great insight! Had the same problem :D

Comment: I ended up creating a library to solve help this problem. https://github.com/justengel/qt_thread_updater

Answer (score 3):

The [Qt documentation for QThreads](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html) provides two popular patterns for using threading.  You can either subclass `QThread` (the old way), or you can use the *Worker Model*, where you create a custom `QObject` with your worker functions and run them in a separate `QThread`.

In either case, you can't directly update the GUI from the background thread, so in your `update` function, the `guiUpdate` call will most likely crash Qt if it tries to change any of the GUI elements.

The proper way to run background processes is to use one of the two `QThread` patterns and communicate with the main GUI thread via `Signals` and `Slots`.

Also, in the following bit of code,

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Class()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
ex.update()
```

`app.exec_` starts the event loop and will block until Qt exits.  Python won't run the `ex.update()` command until Qt has exited and the `ex` window has already been deleted, so you should just delete that command.

Comment: ou, yes. I forgot about ex.update(). I use this fuction from GUI button now so I will delete it. Also thanks for the tips!